# Carport roof out of square a little bit

Tags: roof

I have a carport roof sheathed in plywood (*I did not do that part*). I am ready to put the underlayment on (*Tyvek*). If the roof is slightly out of square, what is the best approach or standard?
I would say it's a few inches out of square for whatever reason. I am not sure why the guys who installed the plywood did lots of cutting.

Lay the first strip of Tyvek square, and trim where needed at the eave, then just go from there? Or don't worry about it, because it's just underlayment.

Comment: Let it run long it is easy to trim later.

Comment: Tyvek can be cut easily with a razor knife to any shape you have.

Comment: The key question is what's going _over_ the Tyvek? Also, "slightly out of square" could be a few inches if the roof is many 10s of feet in each direction, but if it's a single car sized, a few inches is _more_ that _slightly_ out of square! Measure the diagonals - that will tell you exactly how far out it is.

Comment: its more out of square than I thought...may 6 or 7 inches...I will get full measurements tomorrow...I don't believe it was error...just the property lines whomever did it was dealing with...bastarde... the kicker is...I am putting PRB metal roofing over it..good thing my contractor buddy with 30 years experience will help with that one.

Comment: its true freeman.  the tyvek is the least of my worries.  i am addressing how to work with out of square with the underlayment to gain knowledge for installing the drip edge and metal roofing.  I already noticed the drip edge does not meet clean at the corners...so i currently am searching the internet.  I have found the 3-4-5 squaring method for laying out metal panels, but I cannot find anything about the "first" and "last" panels...I am assuming that you trim those to the rake edge...but I would like to see a video on it.

Comment: Is it just the plywood, or is the roof **frame** out of square due to leaning posts or something?  Make sure you don't have a structure that's at risk of falling over.

Comment: Maybe you should ask about the real question then, which seems to be about working with your metal roofing, since underlayment _can_ be installed all kinds of crooked, so long as there's sufficient overlap to keep the wood dry.

Comment: The rakes are both 13 feet within 1/2 inch.  The eave is 17.5"..the ridge 16'10"  One diagonal from lower left to top right is 20' 5"...the other diagonal is 22' 5"....its just a weird shape...probably built that way because of property lines....I will get it figured out...